# Is there a simplified 4-color proof for pixilated maps?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, alternative-proof

> In mathematics, the four color theorem, or the four color map theorem,
> states that no more than four colors are required to color the regions
> of any map so that no two adjacent regions have the same color.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem

What if the map was restricted to a pixelated image, i.e. a grid of colored squares? Would a much simpler proof suffice? Has such a proof been published?

**EDIT 1:** On a pixilated map, at most 4 regions can meet at a point. There is no theoretical limit on a continuous map. So maybe some simplification is possible?

**EDIT 2:** On a finite pixilated map, there is at most a finite number of regions. The maximum is equal to the number of pixels. There is no maximum on even a finite continuous map.

Comment: Any map can be turned into an appropriately-equivalent pixelated map with little effort, so no.

Comment: @NoahSchweber See edit.

Comment: But meeting at a point isn't relevant to colorability. Think about the adjacency graph of the map, not the map itself. There really is no difference.